# How to run a .jar file after every boot on Debian (Raspbian)

Tags: java, linux, jar, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I want to run a .jar file always after I booted up my Raspberry Pi. I know how to run the file in the console:

```
java -jar pi/test.jar
```

But how can I save this command in a executable file and where is the place to save it, that the file starts after boot up? This is not a duplicate because it's different on a Raspberry Pi than on other linux systems.

Comment: cron "@reboot" maybe

Comment: Use cron's `@reboot`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linux run at start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24174134/linux-run-at-start)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use my setup :

save this in `/etc/init.d/raspberryUtils` (change as appropriate)

```
#!/bin/bash
# MyApp
#
# description:raspberryUtils util service

case $1 in
    start)
        /bin/bash /home/developer/raspberryUtils/bootstartup/startServer.sh
    ;;
    stop)
        /home/developer/raspberryUtils/bootstartup/stopServer.sh
    ;;
    restart)
        /home/developer/raspberryUtils/bootstartup/stopServer.sh
        /home/developer/raspberryUtils/bootstartup/startServer.sh
    ;;
esac
exit 0
```

**startServer.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash

java -cp /home/developer/raspberryUtils/dist/RaspberryUtils.jar service.StartServices  &
```

**stopServer.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
# Grabs and kill a process from the pidlist that has the word myapp

pid=`ps aux | grep RaspberryUtils | awk '{print $2}'`
kill -9 $pid
```

this way you can stop,start without restarting the pi too

NOTE:

as mentioned by @Cosu its better using `jps` so stopServer.sh is :

```
#!/bin/bash
# Grabs and kill a process from the pidlist that has the word StartService

pid=`jps | grep StartService | awk '{print $1}'`
kill -9 $pid
```

Comment: Instead of using ps aux to get the procss list you can use `jps`. It might not be an issue in this case but it's a good habit.

Comment: so RaspberryUtils.jar would be my jar-file?

Comment: @PascalAckermann yes mate, just use  `java -cp yourjarFile yourclasswithMain`

Comment: @PascalAckermann also bear in mind that I just copied and paste my code, please change the location accordingly

Answer (score 1):

You can user crontab for executing jar file every time you reboot. In terminal type crontab -e. at last of that code add line "@reboot command(For jar)".
If crontab -e is not working properly that execute export EDITOR=nano and then crontab -e.